# R: Pairing multiple items with adjacent ranking into new columns

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape

This is a follow-up to [R: Pairing of consecutive items into new separate columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61235437/r-pairing-of-consecutive-items-into-new-separate-columns), where pairings of items were moved into columns based on a comparison of values (a group label of the next-highest value was put into a new column).

Not considered there, though, is the possibility of items that have the same value. I'm trying to include these cases such that if the next-highest value in the group has multiple items, then there will be a row for each of those next-highest items.

Given the following data:

```
df = data.frame(
  Name = c('lorem', 'lorem', 'lorem', 'lorem', 'lorem', 'ipsum', 'ipsum', 'ipsum', 'ipsum', 'ipsum', 'dolor', 'dolor', 'dolor', 'dolor', 'dolor', 'dolor'),
  Delay = c(0, 30, 80, 80, 100, 0, 30, 50, 80, 100, 0, 0, 60, 60, 100, 100),
  Group = c('E', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'E', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'D', 'F', 'E')  )
```

The dplyr dense_rank() function applied to the Delay figures provides a pretty clean way of how the pairing should work; within each Name, Groups with rank 1 should be paired with rank 2, 2s would in turn be paired with 3s, 3s with 4s...

```
  Name  Delay Group  Rank
   <chr> <dbl> <chr> <int>
 1 lorem     0 E         1
 2 lorem    30 D         2
 3 lorem    80 C         3
 4 lorem    80 B         3
 5 lorem   100 A         4
 6 ipsum     0 E         1
 7 ipsum    30 D         2
 8 ipsum    50 C         3
 9 ipsum    80 B         4
10 ipsum   100 A         5
11 dolor     0 C         1
12 dolor     0 A         1
13 dolor    60 B         2
14 dolor    60 D         2
15 dolor   100 F         3
16 dolor   100 E         3
```

So the desired output would be (where Step is just the lower ranking of the pair):

```
Name    Source  Target  Step
lorem   E       D       1
lorem   D       C       2
lorem   D       B       2
lorem   B       A       3
ipsum   E       D       1
ipsum   D       C       2
ipsum   C       B       3
ipsum   B       A       4
dolor   C       B       1
dolor   A       B       1
dolor   C       D       1
dolor   A       D       1
dolor   B       F       2
dolor   D       F       2
dolor   B       E       2
dolor   D       E       2
```

I'm unsure whether any clever dplyr grouping might be useful here (I was happy to find that it solved the previous question, but this doesn't seem like it can be done with the same sort-and-look-at-the-next-row-solution). Early on, I was thinking that some kind of embedded loop might be a way to go, but that felt unnecessarily inefficient.

dplyr's dense_rank() seems like it will help, though, to be able to pair Groups that have Ranks with a difference of 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I was on the right track with dense_rank(), and then a self-join did the trick to match the offset:

```
df2 = df %>% group_by(Group) %>% mutate(Round = dense_rank(Delay),
                                       Next = Round + 1) %>%
  ungroup()
df2 = df2 %>%
  inner_join(df2, by = c("Group" = "Group", "Next" = "Round"))
```